# is there a way to identify which iframe send the message to main window when multiple iframes are from same external domain?

Tags: javascript, message, same-origin-policy

I know the `MessageEvent` object has `source` variable, but that seems to be unusable when message comes from different domain. Is there any way to identify which iframe is sending the messages (for example request to resize) if there are several of them on the same top page ?

Comment: _“but that seems to be unusable”_ – please be more specific as to what issue this is causing. MDN explicitly says that this property can be used _“to establish two-way communication between two windows with different origins”_.

Comment: `typeof e.source` == object , but `e.source == iframe` returns false; I can't read from the property. (Firefox 27) , could you put a link to a website with example code ? MDN explicitly says that it is not complete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent

Comment: Have you logged it to console to see what kind of object it is? And what is `iframe`? Please post a full example instead of just bits and pieces that are missing relevant info.

Comment: iframe is irrelevant here e.source is empty object, typeof says object but it has no data, but all other fields of message are ok